# Efficient insert std::list operation

Tags: c++, list, stl

How is the insert operation in std::list implemented? I have tried to read the source code, but it is unreadable for me. My implementation of the insert operation in my list is too slow if I compare it with std::list.insert(). But, where is the problem? I haven't posted the full source code because is too long.

```
if (__size == 0 && index == 0)
    {
        installFirstNode(arr[0]);
        node * tnode;
        for (register msize i=1; i<alen; ++i)
        {
            tnode = allocNode();
            tnode->value = arr[i];
            tail->link = tnode;
            tail = tnode;
        }
        return;
    }
```

This is small fragment of my insert function. I have one idea, std::list uses a memory pool for nodes. But, if it use memory pool, it will be faster ... (not only 30% boost).

I use GCC 4.8

```
void installFirstNode(const T & val)
{
    node * n = allocNode();
    n->value = val;
    head = tail = n;
}
node * allocNode()
{
    node * newNode = (node*)_allocator.alloc(sizeof(node));
    callCtors(newNode);
    newNode->link = nullptr;
    return newNode;
}
template <class T>
void callCtors(T * base, msize size=1)
{
    new (base) T [size];
}
```

_allocator.alloc(sizeof(node)) -> it's simple wrapper for malloc().

alen is simple long variable

Comment: implementation of stl librairies is compiler dependant. the standard only species some properties that the librairies must have

Comment: It's difficult to tell what would be inefficient without seeing the implementations of installFirstNode and allocNode or what alen is

Comment: Why do you care? It's a black box. Let it be.

Comment: A lot of the `std` library is built by people who work full time for years trying to optimize the code, so don't feel bad if your code isn't as fast as theirs.

Comment: How are you running your benchmarks? What compiler flags have you used?

Comment: GCC -O2. Nothink more.

Comment: You might want to throw in `-DNDEBUG` and try `-O3`.

Comment: I know, but, my list will be slover than STL list like If I use -O2. I want to know why.

Comment: @Seraph Sorry but if you're using gcc 4.8 as your compiler, why don't you simply want to use `std::list`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I think you misunderstand the question. They want to know how `std::list` works so that they can figure out why it's so much faster than their home-brew.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I didn't misunderstand it. The answer is "use `std::list`, because you have benchmarked and found it to be superior in performance to your alternative implementation; _how_ it achieved that is irrelevant, and you do not need to study stdlib implementation code."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well when you say it like that...

Comment: I'm sad...I don't know why it is too slow. Malloc is fast, problem is somewhere else.